# Xpath equivalent in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've been trying to get the equivalent of xpath to parse an xpath expression from a dom object in python 3.

Currently I have the below code in python 2.6:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
import xpath

xpath_expr = "//application.../files/file" 
input_xml = "sample xml"
doc = dom.parseString(input_xml)

elements = xpath.find(xpath_expr, doc)
```

The elements contain:

```
[<DOM Element: file at 0x7f06d9d25e60>, <DOM Element: file at 0x7f06d9d297a0>]
```

I've tried it using etree:

```
from lxml import etree

input_xml = "sample xml"
root = etree.fromstring(input_xml)
xpath_expr = "//application.../files/file" 

elements = root.xpath(xpath_expr)
```

The elements contain:

```
[<Element file at 0x7f5098c795f0>, <Element file at 0x7f5098c79590>]
```

However, I'd like the elements of the output array to be of type `DOM Element` and not `Element`.

Comment: what is different in `DOM Element` and `Element` ? Probably there is no difference. And if  you really need  `DOM Element` then don't use `lxml` - you can't get it by changing `xpath_expr`

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from lxml import etree

input_string = ""

root = etree.fromstring(input_string)

xpath_expr = "//application"

elements = root.xpath(xpath_expr)

dom_elements = []

for element in elements:
    dom_elements.append(parseString(etree.tostring(element)).getElementsByTagName("*")[0])
```

```
print dom_elements

[<DOM Element: file at 0x7fe4535b3f38>, <DOM Element: file at 0x7fe4535bf7e8>]
```